# Use cron job for background php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm tryig to send multiple emails using PhpMailer for a notification system. To avoid problems with time delay when a user submit a form I've decided to queue all the email messages storing them into a mysql table then using cron job I'm running a background script to send the queue. This is the script I'm running with cron job

```
include('config/config.php');

require_once(ROOT_PATH.'/helper/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Host = SSE_HOST;  
    $mail->Username = SSE_USER;    
    $mail->Password = SSE_PASSWORD;  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = SSE_SECURE;  
    $mail->Port = 465;  
    $mail->SetFrom(SSE_FROM, SSE_FROM_NAME);
    $mail->addReplyTo(SSE_REPLY, 'Invia Risposta');

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT queue_emails_email, queue_emails_subject, queue_emails_body FROM queue_emails WHERE queue_emails_status = '1' " );

    foreach ($result as $row) {

        $mail->addAddress($row['queue_emails_email']);
        $subject = $row['queue_emails_subject'];
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->MsgHTML($row['queue_emails_body']);


    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row["queue_emails_email"]) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
        break; //Abandon sending
    } else {
        echo "Message sent to :" . $row['queue_emails_email'] . ' (' . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row['queue_emails_email']) . ')<br />';
        //Mark it as sent in the DB
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE queue_emails SET queue_emails_status = '0' WHERE queue_emails_email = '" .
            mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['queue_emails_email']) . "'");

    }
    // Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
    $mail->clearAddresses();

    }
```

This is the mysql table **queue_emails** structure:

```
queue_emails_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
queue_emails_email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
queue_emails_status int(2) DEFAULT '1',
queue_emails_subject TEXT   NOT NULL,
queue_emails_body TEXT NOT NULL
```

Now my question is: if i've got more than one message with different body but same email address what happen if the cron job process gets interrupted? I've tested on my localhost using mailtrap and it seems to work fine but I would like to know is this method can be good on a live server. I don't think my queue would be larger than 200-300 emails. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you just add an ID column to your table and UPDATE based on this ID, not the email address?

Comment: Hi @TodorSimeonov thanks for your quick answer. Sorry i don't understand what you mean by adding an id (is it the user id)?

Comment: In your DB table `queue_emails` - add there a column which can be AUTO INCREMENT and it will be a unique ID of each email message you have to send. Then based on that you can UPDATE with `queue_emails_status = '0'` exactly this row with the email message you have just send, but all other messagee to this user(address) wil stay in the queue. It won't matter if all the table is filled with the same email address.

Comment: Ok I understand now so basically I need to remove the where clause from UPDATE queue_emails SET queue_emails_status = '0' I've already got a queue_emails_id table with auto_increment. So in this way even if cron job process times out it should start from where if was left is it correct? Is there anything else i can implement? I've added $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;  to Phpmailer config as suggested here https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps

Comment: No, its not a good idea to execute UPDATE without a WHERE clause :) You will send just one email message and UPDATE the whole table. I mean change the WHERE clause to something like that `UPDATE ... SET .... WHERE queue_email_id = '$last_email_id';` Compare something that you are sure is unique, not an address that may not be. For example on an online store you will send to the new user 2 subsequent messages - one for succesful registration and one for placed order. And it is good that he receives both of them :)

Comment: Ok but how can I retrieve the last email id? I thought the email would be fine because the update query is inside the foreach process :(

Comment: I don't know how your table looks like. Update your question and write your table structure (CREATE TABLE query).

Comment: Great! See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good that your table contains a separate unique ID, so you wont need to make any chages to database structure. You just have to get your ID value and use it. Modify your `SELECT` like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT queue_emails_id, queue_emails_email,  
    queue_emails_subject, queue_emails_body FROM queue_emails WHERE 
    queue_emails_status = '1' " );
```

Then later when you make the `UPDATE` use this:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE queue_emails SET queue_emails_status = '0' 
    WHERE queue_emails_id = '" . intval($row['queue_emails_id']) . "'");
```

It is just that simple. Now you can be sure that you set zero status to the right message, regardless of how many messages to the same address you have in your queue and you will not loose a message.

By the way your code would loose messages for the same email address if there are more than one in the queue. It will set them all as sent no matter if the `cron` job completes or get interrupted. Let's say you have the following messages:

```
to: john@yahoo.com
to: john@yahoo.com
to: peter@hotmail.com
to: mike@gmail.com
to: john@yahoo.com
```

Your query will return this list, you will start sending messages and send the first message to john@yahoo.com. If `$mail->send()` returns OK you will update all messages to john@yahoo with status=0. So john will receive one message only and the 2-nd and the 5-th messages will be lost (not send to john).

In your question you say that there might be 200-300 messages in the queue. I don't know how often you call this code, I would call it at no more than 5 minutes, so my users receive their mail on time, but if it is too often that means you've go a lot of emails per day. Think about it do you need to keep them all in your table with status=0 or you can delete them to save space.

Comment: Hi Tudor many many thanks for your help, I'm going to test it later and let you know. Regarding your consideration I think i'll call the code every 15 minutes maybe to avoid cron overlap as well (i'm searching on google more info about it as well) then my plan is to run another cron maybe once a day to remove all the rows with status =0 and keep database clean in this way